# Click event handler and ready handler defined in different js file - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

click event handler on add button is not working if i do following(click event defined in add.js and ready event is present in index.js).

If i put click event handler and ready handler in index.js, click event works (alert popup).

Please help me.

Note: #add_button is a static button ( present in index.php, not a dynamic div, i tried live instead of click but that doesn't work too).

**This doesn't work**

```
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/add.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//code
});
```

**add.js**

```
$('#add_button').click(function(event){
 alert('hello');
});
```

**this works if add.js content is directly put into index.js ?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//code
$('#add_button').click(function(event){
 alert('hello');
});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not because they're in different files. It's because the code hooking up the `click` event is running too soon. By putting the `click` setup inside `ready`, you're making it wait until "DOM ready". When it's *not* in the `ready` handler, it runs right away. If that code is above the `#add_button` element, the element won't exist yet, and the handler won't be hooked up.

You have two options:

1. Just put the `script` tag for `add.js` below the element(s) it uses in the markup, e.g.:

   ```
   <input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add">
   <!-- ... -->
   <script src="add.js"></script>
   ```

   Then when the browser runs `add.js`, the element will exist. The `script` tag [could even be *immediately* after the button](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41), but I'd usually recommend the end of the file (e.g., just before the closing `</body>` tag), as indeed do the [YUI folks](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).
2. Use another `ready` handler in `add.js` (you can have as many as you like):

   ```
   // add.js gets its *own* ready handler
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#add_button').click(function(event){
        alert('hello');
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J, i don't prefer inline script, can i use ready handler for every external js file? Any precaution that i need to take when adding ready handler in every file? or any side effect?

Comment: @Praveen: You can have a `ready` in every file if you like. I'm not aware of any side-effects. I believe the handlers will be called in the order they were hooked up. Note that putting `script` tags at the end of `</body>` is no more "inline" than putting them in the `head` section. I agree that putting them in the *middle* of `body` is not a good idea.

Comment: one more question, i have one variable defined in index.js var node_count = 0; i am using same variable in click event handler function defined in add.js, I am getting variable node_count is not defined error.

Comment: btw, click event is now working after defining ready handler in both file but please tell me how to solve variable problem in above comment?

Comment: should i define that variable outside ready handler in index.js, seems to some namespace created by ready anonymous function in index.js

Comment: @Praveen: Declaring a variable within a function makes it local to the function (which is very handy!). If you want to share vars between scripts, my advice would be to use a build process that combines all of your script files into one file (ideally minified, or even compiled by the Closure Compiler). This results in better page load times for your users. *(cont'd)*

Comment: @Praveen: But if you use separate scripts, they'll need to share info via globals. I would create ***one*** global with a name that's likely to be unique, then put any other vars on it. E.g., `window.MyApp = {};` in your first script (which creates a global called `MyApp`). Then `MyApp.foo = 2;` etc. for the individual variables. This keeps the odds of name collisions low (the global namespace is *very* crowded).

Comment: True, everything was working earlier when all files were merged in to index.js, after separation i am getting these issue. As per your suggestion i will try to define a unique variable on window Object.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the handler code in a `.ready` as well in `add.js`. That way, you are sure that the DOM is ready and the button exists before you actually attach the handler to it.

Here's [a shorthand `.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_button').click(function(event){
       alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: ohh can i define ready handler in more than 1 file? like in my case index.js and add.js

Answer (score 1):

always use document.ready to attach event handlers. the external js fuiles are processed at the same time as the html, css and other imported data.

Answer (score 1):

**index.js**

```
function myClickEvent(event) {
 alert('hello');
}
```

**add.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add_button').click(function(e){
      myClickEvent(e);
    });
    });
```

Why your logic does not work?
You are trying to create an self function inside document's ready state which wont be avialable anywhere, since it is executed as soon as the document reaches ready state.

You have to have your functions define somewhere which you can reference whereever you want! The best way is always declare them on top, and utilize anywhere even inside the document ready function.

`$('#add_button').click([])` also might not work due to the reason that sometimes in some browsers you cant determine what has been loaded and whats not! If you keep that also inside "ready" you will get it right! It works perfect!